# Django ORM - use SubQuery in FROM clause

Tags: django, django-orm

Goal: Use RowNumber function to get number for each row, out of that, filter by a value, but retain the appropriate RowNumber given when not applying the filter, since otherwise RowNumber would always return 1.

Before translating to Django ORM, I find it helps to get the SQL syntax, which is this:

```
SELECT rn.row_number, name 
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name), name
       FROM customer ) as rn
WHERE name = 'Juan'
```

**Problem** I can´t manage to translate this to Django ORM. I have tried the following:

```
subq = models.Customer.objects.all().annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=RowNumber(),
                order_by=(F('name'))
            )
           )
```

Here´s where I don´t know how to continue. How do I tell my **models.Customer** to use **subq** as the **FROM** in its query?

Comment: did you manage to fix that?